# fb:comments and iframe apps

Tags: comments, fbml, iframe-app

I've got a FB fan page with an application tab. Application canvas type is Iframe, not FBML. What I want is the ability for a user to comment on the info I put in that tab (simple fb comments form that you can add in your app or website). Now, `<fb:comments>` works for "Like" action, but fails to post any coments. The form itself is visible, but when you click "post", nothing happens. 
I define `xid`, `returnurl`, `showform`, `canpost` params", tried various samples, and it still doesn't work - no error is shown, but no action whatsoever. I'd put the social plugin in there but FB strips off the scripts or iframes even if they're from the same (facebook) domain. If it helps, here's the sample code I've used:

```
<fb:comments xid="veryuniqueid_123" canpost="true" candelete="true" numposts="5" showform="1" publish_feed="0" simple="1" reverse="1"></fb:comments>
```

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks,
d.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Loaded JS SDK from `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/` , then added the code provided by facebook in `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/` , "XFBML" version (since iframe isn't supported and HTML5 is a bit too early).